# Rooted my phone Now on to SD problems

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I rooted my phone and was able to delete several apps I don't need,(Touchpal, Browser (electing to use google for these) Problem though. Now I want to move the programs I do use , but are not integral to the phone, onto an external sd card.

I got a nice 32 Gig card,mounted it in the phone and still can't get the phone to transfer any files there.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about moving system apps (apps that came with the phone) to the external sdcard?

Comment: Any apps at all. I can access the card through my computer but the phone won't let me put anything on the SD.

Comment: What phone are you using? What Android version?

Comment: Android 4.0 Model ZTE N9500 Carrier:　Sprint

Comment: I formatted the card to NFTS and put it back in the phone. Came up as blank/incompatible sd. Here's the kicker. The phone allowed me to format the card while mounted. Hopefully that worked.

Comment: Apart from the fact that almost no Android device supports NTFS natively (I've never heard of a single one): Did re-formatting the card solve your issue? If so, it would be absolutely cool if you could [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154), so others can profit from your solution :) Thanks in advance!